# Not getting login screen when setting currency to EUR on PayPal Mobile Payment Library on Android

Tags: android, localization, paypal

I'm using PayPal's Mobile Payment Library on Android to accept payments for services. However I'm not getting the login screen popped up when setting the currency to EUR. Works fine only on USD. Anyone might have any idea why? I'm not getting any messages, errors or callbacks what-so-ever. Would appreciate any help. Thanks

```
public void PayPalButtonClick(View arg0) {
          // Create a basic PayPal payment
          PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment();

          // Set the currency type
          payment.setCurrencyType("EUR");

          // Set the recipient for the payment (can be a phone number)
          payment.setRecipient("email@email.com");

         // Set the payment amount, excluding tax and shipping costs
          payment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(9999.9));

          // Set the payment type--his can be PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS,
          // PAYMENT_TYPE_SERVICE, PAYMENT_TYPE_PERSONAL, or PAYMENT_TYPE_NONE
          payment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_SERVICE);

          // PayPalInvoiceData can contain tax and shipping amounts, and an
          // ArrayList of PayPalInvoiceItem that you can fill out.
          // These are not required for any transaction.
          PayPalInvoiceData invoice = new PayPalInvoiceData();

          // Set the tax amount
          invoice.setTax(new BigDecimal(99.0));

          Intent paypalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment, this);
          this.startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually found the answer... quite stupid really. The Subtotal was 9999.0. All I did was reduce this number to say, 99.0. The reason might have been that when switched to EUR, the limit was exceeded or something. Not sure really, but it worked. So be careful of those high default numbers I guess.

Answer (score 2):

you're right... With EUR currency the default per transaction limit is 8,000.00€

You can check it [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/)